# MVC Web Api Route with default action not working

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api

In my `TestController` I have the following:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<String> Active()
    {
        var result = new List<string> { "active1", "active2" };

        return result;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public String Active(int id)
    {
        var result = new List<string> { "active1", "active2" };

        return result[id];
    }
```

In `RouteConfig` the mapping is:

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

In a browser the following request works:

```
api/test/active/1
```

But this returns a **Internal Server Error**:

```
api/test/active
```

What do you have to do to return a *action* that may or maynot have a parameter in a similar manner to the default Get?

**Update 1**
As Cuong Le suggested, changing the ordering of routes helped, the routes are now:

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I had to remove `action = ""` from the ActionApi route otherwise the standard Get on the other controllers stopped working (i.e. api/values)

api/test/active is now resolving, but I now get a 500 Internal Server Error for /api/test is it possile to have both resolves, so api/test would return "all" and /test/active only return "some"?

Comment: What kind of Internal Server Error you get? Multiple actions were found?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to get a more detailed message, I am running just using debug in Visual Studio, is there a web.config setting or something to get a more verbose error?

Comment: I have not tried to debug bu I think you can see verbose error from debugging. You also can set up <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/> on web.config and use filter to see the error thrown out. As your questions, I have not clear answer so far :(.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably getting confused since you have two methods named action. Try deleting or renaming one of them and see if that works.

Comment: If I comment out Active(int id) in the controller I get a 400 Bad Request for the request to api/test/active.  I would have thought two methods one with an one without parameters would be OK as the default example Get() and Get(int id) work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to provide a default value for the parameter,

```
[HttpGet]
public String Active(int id = 0)
{
    var result = new List<string> { "active1", "active2" };

    if (id == 0) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return result[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: Darrel, the return type will be different, if id == 0 a Enumerable would be returned.  What I am trying to understand is the routing when you add "actions" to the Url.