# ASP.NET Routing not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling to make Route Prefix working or probably have misunderstanding about Routes in ASP.NET Web API

Here is my code:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
  {
    // GET: api/Test
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Test/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetValue")]
    public string GetValue(int id)
    {
        return "best";
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetValue1")]
    public string GetValue1(int test)
    {
        return "GetValue";
    }
}
```

Here is the status of each call

1. `localhost:52154/api/test/Getvalue1/1` (HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found)
2. `localhost:52154/api/test/Getvalue1?test=1` ( 
   The webpage cannot be found )
3. `localhost:52154/api/test/Getvalue?id=1` (Works return "value" but does not call the GetValue Method)
4. `localhost:52154/api/test/1` (Works return "value")
5. `localhost:52154/api/test/` (Works return "value1","value2")

Please let me know what to do to make the GetValue1 and GetValue route work. I did update the NuGet pacakge for ASP.NET to Web Api 2.2

WebApiConfig looks like this

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Could you show us your WebApiConfig if you made changes there?

Comment: I don't think using 'Get' in your route names is going to work, as its a special term that is already being translated. Try `[Route("RetriveValue")]`

Comment: Its seems like your web api routing is not correctly configured. With the default routing all get requests will be mapped to the Get method, Posts to  Post method etc. Most likely your WebApiConfig.cs has a line containing `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}`", which you should change to `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` to also map the action. Your `[Route]` attributes wont be needed for this.

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: see my message above

Comment: @YvoCilon  Change the route mapping to 'code' config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }   but still not working. Infact none of the request work now

Comment: Are you calling localhost:52154/api/test/get  ?

Comment: And you should remove the [Route] annotations, Then you can call them like so **localhost:52154/api/test/Getvalue1/1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution which worked for me
        public IEnumerable Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

```
    // GET: api/Test/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
    [HttpGet]

    public string GetValue(int id)
    {
        return "best";
    }


    [HttpGet]

    public string RetriveValue(int test)
    {
        return "GetValue";
    }
```

courtesy of 
[How to bypass the exception multiple actions were found in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739288/how-to-bypass-the-exception-multiple-actions-were-found-in-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

Use This : `[ActionName("Getvalue1")]`

hope this works!!